# What are the valid reasons to use ContentPresenter outside of template?

Tags: .net, wpf

I stumbled upon an article by Den Delimarsky on [What is a ContentPresenter?](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/what-contentpresenter) which says:

> In WPF there is an element called ContentPresenter, that is often used inside control templates, as well as inside the root application markup.

I don't understand the "inside the root application markup" part, because I thought that ContentPresenter can only used inside of a ControlTemplate.

The role of the ContentPresenter is quite clear when used in a ControlTemplate, but what are the valid reasons to use ContentPresenter outside of a template's markup?

Comment: Hi Dreamer, this is on-topic here, but can you go a little more into what you're trying to do so people know how best to answer?

Comment: I stumbled upon this article: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/what-contentpresenter which says "In WPF there is an element called ContentPresenter, that is often used inside control templates, as well as inside the root application markup. " and I didn't get that "inside the root application markup." part, because I though that ContentPresenter can only used  inside of a ControlTemplate. Hence is my question.

Comment: I added your explanation back into the question: thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

(This seems to be a quite outdated reply.)

There are valid uses of `ContentPresenter` everywhere. My primary use of it is to dispatch the view by the runtime type of the content.

Let me explain: imagine that you have a property of type `Animal` in your VM, so you'd like to display it somewhere in your UI. If you have a single UI for any kind of `Animal`, you can put it into a `UserControl`, and use a construct like

```
<AnimalControl DataContext="{Binding Animal}"/>
```

However imagine that you've got a bunch of different animals, say, `Toad`s, `Human`s and `Unicorn`s. So you'd like to differentiate between them (maybe you've developed several `UserControl`s for them). You do it in the following way:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Animal}"/>
```

In order for the correct view to be used, you need the following `DataTemplate`s to be in scope:

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type vm:Unicorn}">
    <UnicornControl/>
</DataTemplate>
```

etc. Usually people get such a functionality using `TemplateSelector`/`ContentTemplateSelector`, but this way is valid, too, and seems to be simpler (you can shuffle template scopes with custom styles, a la CSS).

Answer (score 1):

There are no reasons. You should use `ContentControl` rather then `ContentPresenter` outside of a template.